# how to display/update black and white image using "set" function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, colormap

I am doing a project on video processing, in which images are processed and displayed and updated using the code below:

```
hFigure=figure(1);
set(hFigure,'Position', [50, 250, 400, 300]);

IM1=getdata()  % get frame from video object

%initialise
figure(1)
handles=image(IM1);
IM1=binarize(IM1);

Loop  %update frame 
    IM1=getdata()  % get frame from video object
    IM1=binarize(IM1);
    set(handles,'CData',IM1);
end loop
```

The output image is blue and yellow, not black and white. Online instruction says when `CData` is `uint8`, then output color will be RGB; when `logical`, output will be B&W. Can any body tell me how to set `CData` to `logical` type? Or, do you know other alternatives to settle this?

Comment: Use colormap(gray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed data will only be RGB if the `CData` is `M x N x 3`. If it is only `M x N`, it will be displayed using the axes' colormap instead. In your case it is using the default colormap (`parula`) so you'll want to either convert your input to RGB or use the `gray` colormap to display a black and white image.

**RGB Approach**

```
set(handles, 'CData', repmat(IM, [1 1 3]))
```

**Colormap Approach**

```
hFigure = figure(1);
set(hFigure,'Position', [50, 250, 400, 300]);

IM1 = getdata()  % get frame from video object

handles = image(IM1);
colormap(hFigure, gray(2))
```